# Preposition question: should I use 'from' or 'in'?

Tags: prepositions

Fans will delight in this character Tonie jam-packed with popular songs from the well-loved adventures of/from/in/depicted in? the animated series, Mr Bean.

Not sure which preposition is best here, without overcomplicating things... Using 'from' twice sounds wrong to me...

Any help is so much appreciated. Every day is a school day!

Comment: Can songs actually be 'depicted'?

Comment: @Cascabel The adventures, not the songs, are depicted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that both "from" and "depicted in" work. But to avoid the repetition of "from", I would say, "depicted in".

Comment: Why these options? Why don't the other options work? Answers are far more useful when they include explanations.